# Steam Mic Issues

Tags: steam

Steam says that it has detected my headset and when I test the microphone it works fine. When I get into a game nothing changes with my settings but no one can hear me. I have no clue what the problem is because by the looks of it there is no problem. Steam has no clue about this issue and it's really bugging me.

Comment: There should be some symbols in the top right corner. Can you take a screenshot of them, or at least describe the microphone-looking one?

Comment: I'm not sure what symbols you're looking for (in game or on the steam app). Either way I don't see any. All I know is that whenever someone is saying something there's a box with their name in it on the right side of the screen and there's a little yellow microphone that pops up above their head. I don't get either one.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic voice detection can be unreliable, especially if you don't spend time calibrating it. In this case, the threshold was too high.

Switching to push-to-talk fixes this and is a lot easier than calibrating the voice levels. It can be done from the broadcasting menu. Just remember not to use a button you need in the game.